# How to prevent 404 errors when browser is refreshed?

Tags: angular-cli, angular13, html-webpack-plugin, webpack.config.js

I want Angular(v.13) can initialise and handle routing instead of trying to handle it on the server.

I've searched "Update webpack dev server config" which tells the webpack dev server to always serve /index.html regardless of the URL path...

But I can't find webpack.congif.js file.

could anyone give me any advice please?

Comment: You should not have 404 errors on your development machine. The angular development server (It is webpack dev server actually) manages it properly. However, when you run your app in a server for production or testing, you should configure it in a way that it returns index.html for paths that doesn't point to files.  The way you configure It depends on the specific server you are using

Comment: There was no 404  errors on my development.  Just wonder is there any way I can handle 404 errors on the frontend side not on the server when I run my app? thanks again.